# Reducing an Image Size without Losing its Quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

Is there a best way in Photoshop to reduce the image size without losing its quality?

Whenever I reduce the size of the image it seems like a little blurry and reduces its quality. What should I do in order to retain its quality?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Image>Image Size>Resample Image and choose Bicubic Sharper from the dropdown menu. It had just solved my issue.

Comment: @cma: If you found something that fixed it for you, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @wuffers: sorry. by that time, i can't post my own answer because i have no enough points to do so. by now, i can already answer my own question, so be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image` > `Image Size` > `Resample Image` and choose `Bicubic Sharper` from the dropdown menu.

It had just solved my issue. ;)

Comment: Our wedding photographer took photos using only 2 megapixel, but was able to create a 24x18 blown up image. I asked how he did it, and he said he resized it using "Bicubic Sharper" :)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot avoid losing quality when reducing the size of an image; one can hope only to mitigate the quality loss.

When resizing images in Photoshop, the default is to use a softer Bicubic sampler; the comment above to use the Bicubic Sharper would be a good start. It is not, however, always appropriate for all images.

Second, I suggest sticking to multiples of the image width and height. For example, if your original image is 1000x1000, you should get very acceptable results at 250x250, 500x500, 750x750. 398x398, however, is apt to look a bit more blurry.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Size in pixels or size in bytes?

#### If you want it reduced in bytes:

Go to save for web and device from file menu.
This option won't play with your image. It just reduces the size to some extent to make it appropriate for the web.

#### If you want to reduce its size in pixels:

Create a document of your desired size, for example, 400×400.
Now, drag your desired layer/image to this new document, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Just match the corners from transform corners, it won't look blurred.
And if you're going to make an image of 400×400 to 200×200, it will loose its quality for sure.

Comment: You are genius man :D you pointed me to a great feature "save for web"

Comment: Welcome @MuhammedRefaat though this option save a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Before resizing , convert it into smart object.

Right click on the layer of the image ---> Convert it into Smart Object

then resize the smart object using Free Transform tool.

I found it helpful. But there would be a bit of a compromise in image quality.

Note: Do your edit work on the image before you go to smart object. Else you have to raster it again will sure be a loss in quality.

Answer (score 3):

When size decreases we need to compromise bit of quality, however the quality change may be ignorable while comparing with size.
There are several steps you can do.

1. Save as for web (GIF), it will reduce huge size
2. Crop or resize the document according to requirement.
3. Choose the quality while saving to reduce the size.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options:

1. Use .gif format, it will reduce the size but if the image has many colours then you will lose quality.
2. Use .png, it helps but does not reduce the size by much.
3. Use .webp, a new format introduced by Google. Not researched a lot but will update once I have a tangible answer.

Comment: Do you have a tangible answer yet? :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had a very large (3300px x 2550px).jpg file with a logo that was mainly text. for the webpage I wanted it 150px wide. When resized in photoshop some of the text was completely unreadable.

Not all done in Photoshop, but I imported the original jpg image into inkscape (free vector graphics sw and resized it in there). I then re-saved(exported) it as .png and voila, very little distortion!

Dont know how well it would work for non-text but worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with the need to reduce an image so that it could be uploaded to my Social Network profile image and banner.

I tried using iMac's ColorSyynUtility...and although this did reduce the size/pixel...it also drastically reduced the quality.

I was able to overcome my problem by simply importing the image into Microsoft Word...and minimising the image her to my desired size. Then I would take a 'screen shot' of the image and use this image to upload to my Social Networking site.

It worked and the image/s look great!
Obviously this would be no good for printing...but for the web it works!

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Try Using Windows 7's Paint Tool..
Click on Resize and adjust your height and width according to you.
It will not blur your image as well as also reduce your size in kb/mb.

Answer (score 3):

In case of JPG files just try saving them with lower quality JPEG compression. Instead of 90% (which is the default settings for most of the cameras today) save it with something like 68%. You will be unable to notice almost any visible difference, but the file size is almost half!

I recommend this for every photographer. Just set your camera to save images at "eco" or "std" quality and you will have much less trouble moving your holiday pictures around and sharing them with friends using flash drives and such. Using something like Faststone Image Viewer you can bulk convert your old photos to around 68% JPEG quality to save a lot of hdd space. This is really much better way then lowering picture resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem - I edited a picture in Photoshop that I wanted to use in an Adobe Illustrator document. When I reduced the size using "Image Size" in photoshop, the quality was greatly reduced, even with the Bicubic Sharper setting. So I tried saving the larger image as a jpeg & dragging it into the Illustrator document & resizing it there, but the picture again became very pixelated. Then I saved it as a png file and dragged that into Illustrator, and this seemed to keep a much better quality when I resized it!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a chat site; we're not interested in what you had for breakfast today, and we're not very interested in things that you tried that didn't work. Please focus on the _answer_ to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have your document set to a resolution of 300 dpi. A few times I've forgotten and it's automatically opened with only 72 DPI and I have trouble reducing High Res images.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends if photoshop image has something applied to it... I personally prefer GIMP find it more reliable. If you want a case study about photoshop, irfan view, GIMP and other services you can find it [here](https://sfaturiit.ro/en/resize-pictures-without-losing-quality/) . I recently tried to reduce a image from 600x900 to 596x894 (was a photographer's image), and I found out that photoshop changes the image brightness..

Comment: is this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by using PowerPoint.  Simply insert the image into a blank slide, then reduce it to the size you want.  Then right-click on the image and select "Save as Picture".  You should not lose any resolution.  I used a MAC, but imagine that PowerPoint for Windows allows you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create the logo as much as you can big(a4 size will suit)
In the print screan , just resize the image using zoom dialog box , or just enter values as you want in size box.

Tc always

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://tinypng.com/

This reduces Image size to almost  70% without affecting any quality

Comment: Please be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirm this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post.